# Other than safety qualifications, was there any technical/engineering reason why propulsive landing was cancelled for the DragonV2?

Tags: propulsion, landing, spacex-starship, dragon-v2

The Dragon V2 cannot perform a propulsive landing. But the Starship will be making propulsive landings. Why?

Comment: The heat shield on Dragon would have needed holes for the landing legs.  Starship has its heat shield on the side.

Comment: @geoffc Space shuttle had its landing gear on heat shield's side, therefore this does not seem like a technical reason.

Comment: Do you need landing legs for a water landing?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a multiple dupe, but:  Starship is more than just a capsule, and further the total mass pretty much precludes parachutes (I believe).    Dragonv2 is not intended to land on non-atmospheric places (moon, Mars) but Starship is.